Prevent overly window (mis-)management
I have EMACS window normally split in two panes (C-x 3), left is for editing, right is for command line for example. I edit .po file in the left pane: I select an entry, hit ENTER and subedit buffer occupies the right pane. Then when I hit C-c C-c upon finishing the edit, the buffer is destroyed and the pane as well.
Is there an easy way to prevent this destroying window behaviour? Or maybe just split the left pane vertically before entering subedit will do too (Currently I'm deep into EMACS manual on displaying buffers, but I'm already almost lost).
Upd. Probably that's not entirely correct in po-mode code. I see this in po-subedit-abort (which is called from po-subedit-exit):
 (or (one-window-p) (delete-window))

I don't see the reason for destroying the window here, because po-mode hasn't created it.

Well, I'm still not sure po-mode has the right to destroy the windows, but I've setup my custom window splitting here, so it's not a problem anymore.
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '(
    ("\\*django\\.po\\*"
     (display-buffer-below-selected)
     (window-height . 12)))

